# Am I using a wrong numerical method?

Tags: performance, matlab, numeric, symbolic-math

This is the code:

```
f = dsolve('D3y+12*Dy+y = 0 ,y(2) = 1 ,Dy(2) = 1, D2y(2) = -1');
feval(symengine, 'numeric::solve',strcat(char(f),'=1'),'t=-4..16','AllRealRoots')
```

If I remove `'AllRealRoots'` option it works fast and finds a solution, but when I enable the option Matlab does not finish for an hour. Am I using a wrong numerical method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, straight from the documentation for [`numeric::solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-solve.html):

> If eqs is a non-polynomial/non-rational equation or a set or list containing such an equation, then the equations and the appropriate optional arguments are passed to the numerical solver numeric::fsolve.

So, as your equation `f` is non-polynomial, you should probably call [`numeric::fsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-fsolve.html) directly. However, even with the `'MultiSolutions'` it fails to return more than one root over your range (A bug perhaps? – I'm using R2013b). A workaround is to call [`numeric::realroots`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-realroots.html) to get bounds on each of the district real roots in your range and then solve for them separately:

```
f = dsolve('D3y+12*Dy+y = 0 ,y(2) = 1 ,Dy(2) = 1, D2y(2) = -1');
r = feval(symengine, 'numeric::realroots', f==1, 't = -4 .. 16');

num_roots = numel(r);
T = zeros(num_roots,1); % Wrap in sym or vpa for higher precision output
syms t;
for i = 1:num_roots
    bnds = r(i);
    ri = feval(symengine, '_range', bnds(1), bnds(2));
    s = feval(symengine, 'numeric::fsolve', f==1, t==ri);
    T(i) = feval(symengine, 'rhs', s(1));
end
```

The resultant solution vector, `T`, is double-precision (allocate it as `sym` or `vpa` you want higher precision):

```
T =

  -0.663159371123072
   0.034848320470578
   0.999047064621451
   2.000000000000000
   2.695929753727520
   3.933983894260340
   4.405822476913172
   5.868112290810963
   6.108685019679461
```

You may be able to remove the `for` loop if you can figure out how to cleanly pass in the output of `'numeric::realroots'` to `'numeric::fsolve'` in one go (it's doable, but may require converting stuf to strings unless you're clever).

Another (possibly even faster) approach is to switch to using the numeric (floating-point) function [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) for the second half after you bound all of the roots:

```
f = dsolve('D3y+12*Dy+y = 0 ,y(2) = 1 ,Dy(2) = 1, D2y(2) = -1');
r = feval(symengine, 'numeric::realroots', f==1, 't = -4 .. 16');

num_roots = numel(r);
T = zeros(num_roots,1);
g = matlabFunction(f-1); % Create anonymous function from f
for i = 1:num_roots
    bnds = double(r(i));
    T(i) = fzero(g,bnds);
end
```

I checked and, for your problem here and using the default tolerances, the resultant `T` is within a few times machine epsilon (`eps`) of the `numeric::fsolve'` solution.